# How is gas adjusted for a transfer in solidity?

Tags: solidity, remix, gas, metamask, gas-estimate

I am using Remix with Metamask on the Ropsten test system, and when I try and transfer Wei I get a gas error. I tried a few combinations but there are various errors relating to gas.

Has anyone any example code for this?

> Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The
>   transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

```
        address public mywallet = 0xcDDb122bb4dCe8AcF90078E0e853b1414d10EDb0;
        bool public status = false;

        function payUser (uint amount) public  payable returns (bool) {
          uint GAS_LIMIT = 4000000;
       //   userAddress.transfer.gas(GAS_LIMIT)(amount);
       //  status =  mywallet.call.value(amount).gas(GAS_LIMIT)();
         mywallet.transfer(amount);
         return status;
        }

        function getBalance(address walletAddress) public view returns (uint) {
            return walletAddress.balance;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to fund the contract first. Otherwise if the contract has a balance of 0, when you call `payUser` with any value greater than 0, it will always fail.